# Swift: Slowing Multiple Calls to a WebService

Tags: swift, web-services, asynchronous

I am working on an app that is sending several requests to a webservice.  As I am getting further into development, I am finding that the webservice is getting overwhelmed and I need to slow things down a bit.  I would like to send each request to the Webservice individually and wait until the previous one completes before sending the next.  Here is the function that is using a loop to make the calls to the webservice:

```
func syncronize(){

    for operation in syncOperations{
        switch operation{
            case "listPhone":
            let listRequest = WSListRequest(requestType: operation, searchCriteria: [SearchCriteria(name: "name", value: "%")], returnTags: [])
            _ = HTTPPost(method: "POST", body: listRequest.xml, operation: operation, credentials: creds)
        default:
            let listRequest = WSLListRequest(requestType: operation, searchCriteria: [SearchCriteria(name: "name", value: "%")], returnTags: ["name"])
            _ = HTTPPost(method: "POST", body: listRequest.xml, operation: operation, credentials: creds)
        }
    }
}
```

The HTTPPost function looks like this:

```
class HTTPPost: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

var componentDebug = false
var user = String()
var password = String()
var server = String()
var port = String()
var body = NSString()
var response = Data()

init(method: String, body: NSString, operation: String, credentials: WSCredential){
    super.init()
    let bodyData = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let userPasswordString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", credentials.userName, credentials.password)
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString, "Content-Type" : "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"]
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10.0

    // create the user request
    let urlString = NSString(format: "https://%@:%@/ws/", credentials.server, credentials.port)
    let url = URL(string: urlString as String)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = method
    request.httpBody = bodyData
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)

    _ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        let responseParser = XMLParser(data: data!)
        let responseParserDelegate = XMLResponseParser(operation: operation)
        responseParser.delegate = responseParserDelegate
        responseParser.parse()

        // DEBUGGING OPTIONS
        //print(response)
        //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.response = data!
        })


    }).resume()
}



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
}
```

I'm a newbie when it comes to Asyncronous programming and could use some help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semaphore so that one task does not begin until the previous one has finished. Here's a demo

```
// The semaphore value is like the size of a token pool. After you've taken
// all the tokens in the pool, you must wait until a task returns its token
// back to the pool. Here we only have 1 token (1 request at a time)
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

// task1 is a request that will take at least 5 seconds to respond
let task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/delay/5")!) { data, response, error in
    print("Task1 is done")
    semaphore.signal()  // release the token
}

// task2 is a faster request
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org")!) { data, response, error in
    print("Task2 is done")
    semaphore.signal()  // release the token
}

// Never wait on your main queue, always do that in the background
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    semaphore.wait() // take a token, wait if needed.
                     // There will never be a wait here, but included for consistency
    print("starting task 1")
    task1.resume()

    semaphore.wait() // take a token, wait if needed
    print("starting task 2")
    task2.resume()
}
```

With the semaphore, the output is what you would expect:

```
starting task 1
Task1 is done
starting task 2
Task2 is done
```

Take out the 2 `semaphore.wait()` lines and can see how both of these requests will be sent at the same time:

```
starting task 1
starting task 2
Task2 is done
Task1 is done
```

Comment: I'll see if I can make this work, but each task is not coded separately, so I'm not sure if this will work.  As you can see in my example, the task runs multiple times using a loop from a list of operations in an array.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I made this work!  Thank you so much for your suggestion.  This one had me blocked for a long time!  I defined the semaphore globally, that solved the issue with the loop.  Thank you so much!